# Como utilizar MAX() en SQL server para mostrar unicamente el valor maximo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Intenté con lo siguiente:

```
SELECT idOfertasEmpleo, MAX(salario) AS SalarioMax 
FROM Empresa.OfertasEmpleo;
```

Pero me da el siguiente error

> Column 'Empresa.OfertasEmpleo.idOfertasEmpleo' is invalid in the
>   select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

También intenté con un GROUP BY:

```
SELECT idOfertasEmpleo, MAX(salario) AS SalarioMax 
FROM Empresa.OfertasEmpleo GROUP BY idOfertasEmpleo;
```

Pero me los muestra de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> y yo sólo necesito el maximo y mostrar a quien le pertenece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque se selecciona `idOfertasEmpleo`, entonces te pone ese dato:

```
SELECT idOfertasEmpleo, MAX(salario) AS SalarioMax 
FROM Empresa.OfertasEmpleo GROUP BY idOfertasEmpleo;
```

Si se necesita solo el `salario`, seria así:

```
SELECT MAX(salario) AS SalarioMax FROM Empresa.OfertasEmpleo;
```

Comment: Pero, y si necesito mostrar tambien a quien le pertenece el salario maximo?

Comment: Seria asi

SELECT *
FROM Empresa.OfertasEmpleo 
WHERE salario IN ( SELECT MAX(salario) FROM Empresa.OfertasEmpleo)

Hay que tener en cuenta que puede devolver mas de un resultado si hay 2 que tienen el mismo salario y es el mas alto

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es obtener el salario máximo, pues hacer lo siguiente:

- Usa `GROUP BY` dado que trabajas con una función de agregación `MAX`
- En el `SELECT` invoca a la columna que te ayudará a identificar de quien es, por ejemplo esa columna pudiera llamarse `nombre`
- Usa la instrucción `TOP` con un valor de `1` para indicarle solo te devuelva una fila del conjunto de resultados

Quedando tu consulta así:

```
SELECT TOP 1 nombre, MAX(salario) AS SalarioMax 
FROM Empresa.OfertasEmpleo
GROUP BY nombre;
```

Si necesitas agregar la columna `idOfertasEmpleo` considera que esta pudiera alterar el resultado esperado y no mostrar de primera mano el salario mayor y a quien le corresponde; si aún así lo necesitas considero que al final de tu consulta debes hacer uso de `ORDER BY`

```
ORDER BY idOfertasEmpleo DESC;
```